# In Flutter how to zoom one image while icons which are overlaid over the image will not move i.e. always keep those icons lined up perfectly?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In Flutter I have done overlaying of two icons on one image as shown,[icons overlay on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UFrq.png),
These icons should be in the fixed position as shown here,[icons actual position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF507.png)
Now if I zoom the image, the icons are getting shifted along with the zooming as shown below
[icon shifted while zooming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWClq.png)
Again icons are shifted for zooming in as shown here  [icon again shifted while zooming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25acM.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}


  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Image Zoom Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: Zoom(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class Zoom extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  MyStatelessWidget createState()=> MyStatelessWidget();
}
/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends State<Zoom> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0),
        color: Colors.white,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        
          child: new Stack(   
          children: <Widget>[
              InteractiveViewer(
              child: Image.asset("images/ncdscreen_oralimage.png"),              
              
            ),
            new Positioned(
              left: 80.0,
              top: 6.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.radio_button_checked,
              color: Colors.black)
            ), 
            new Positioned(
              left: 110.0,
              top: 24.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.radio_button_checked,
              color: Colors.black)
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I expect those icons should not move when I do zooming of the image, It should be fixed on that position and while scrolling as shown below

[original position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQydH.png)

[after zooming, the icons' position still fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGfMX.png)

Comment: Does this point need to be placed by the user?

Comment: No, it is already there, I mean at the time of fetching image from assets, those two radio-button icons are also overlaid upon that image in the same time, that's why the positions of them are already hard-coded using padding. Those two icons are not getting placed by mouse click.

Comment: The zooming of the picture is done by the plug-in, and it is difficult to have a relationship between the picture and the point